# Permission class in InfoPath C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, infopath

I am new to InfoPath as well as SharePoint 2010. I am trying to set the permissions of an infopath form so that if a checkbox is checked in that form, only certain user groups in SharePoint can view that form. However, I have found very little documentation online about the Permission class and almost no example code. Does anyone have any example code they could post or links to sites that have information about the Permission class?

Just incase, here is the code I have so far:

```
            string chkBox = GetNodeValue("/my:myTipLead/my:OBDM/my:DocumentDesignation/my:AllCISOL1And2Members");
            if (chkBox == "AllCISOL1And2Members")
            {

            }
```

Edit: If anyone has any info on any of the other SharePoint/InfoPath classes that could accomplish assigning permission levels to a specific form, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed permissions on my Infopath form based on group membership, however was unable to find a way. Here's the [closest that I found.](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2010/09/)

It suggests that you might create a Sharepoint List to emulate the role/permission that you're going to use in Infopath. The drawback is you need to maintain the security in two places. However retrieving the 'permission' from a Sharepoint List becomes possible in Infopath.